# check if string contains anything outside of the character set swift

Tags: swift, nsstring, xcode7

Hi I want to check if the user types in a string that contains anything outside of the character set (contains characters that are not specified in my set):

"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_-."

How can I achieve this? thanks in advance!

update

I tried using

```
var characterSet:NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
if (searchTerm!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterSet.invertedSet).location == NSNotFound){
println("No special characters")
```

}

but i'm getting a type 'range?' has no member 'location' error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, Just use NSCharacterSet like this :-

```
let name1="myname" // Input
let characterSet:  NSMutableCharacterSet = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
characterSet.addCharactersInString("_-.")
name1.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(characterSet).isEmpty // If this return true, you enetered the right charcters
```

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only trims the ends off the string. Also, the question is "string contains anything outside of character set". You result only returns true if the string *only* contains characters outside the set. While "myname" will correctly return false and ":)" will return true, "my!name" will return also return false.

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom NSCharacterSet charactersInString and check if the character type is member of that invertedSet:

```
extension NSCharacterSet {
    func characterInStringIsMember(aString: String) -> Bool {
        var result = false
        aString
            .characters
            .map{ UInt16(String($0).unicodeScalars.first?.value ?? 0) }
            .forEach { result = characterIsMember($0) }
        return result
    }
}


let customCharSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_-.").invertedSet

let stringTest = "abc"

if customCharSet.characterInStringIsMember(stringTest) {
    print(true)  //
} else {
    print(false) // "false\n"
}

let stringTest2 = "abc%"

if customCharSet.characterInStringIsMember(stringTest2) {
    print(true)  // "true\n"
} else {
    print(false)
}
```